# RavenDB adds integer to ID when ends with a slash

Tags: ravendb

I use RavenDB 1.0.0.426

I just experienced a weird scenario when importing data from an external source into RavenDB:

I chose to use the same unique ID as the external source uses, prefixed with a certain string. But. When I store a document with an ID that ends with a '/', raven automatically adds a number to the end of the ID, causing the document to NOT overwrite existing document stored with the same id.

I have recreated a simple scenario to cause the error:

**The type I save:**

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Foo(string id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

**Method saving a doc with the same id 10 times and afterwards checks the document count:**

```
public void RunTest(string id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        using (var doc = new DocumentStore() { Url = "http://pc-009:8080/" })
        {
            doc.Initialize();
            using (var session = doc.OpenSession())
            {
                session.Store(new Foo(id));
                session.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

            // Wait for the data to be persisted
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

    using (var doc = new DocumentStore() { Url = "http://pc-009:8080/" })
    {
        doc.Initialize();
        using (var session = doc.OpenSession())
        {
            var foos = session.Query<Foo>();
            int fooCount = foos.Count();
            // ASSERT HERE THAT fooCount is 1
        }
    }
}
```

**Running the method with "id1" successfully overwrites existing documents:**

```
RunTest("id1"); // Works fine
```

**Running method with "id1/" ends up creating 10 documents in the database:**

```
RunTest("id1/"); // Results in multiple documents to be created
```

I know that if you do not define your own ID, raven will autogenerate doc-ids on the fly, but is the behavior I describe above by design?

Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stephan,
This is expected, when your key ends with /, it asks ravendb to use identity generation strategy.
See the docs here:
http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-api-key-generation

If you want a key that ends with /, you can url encode the keys

Comment: Thanks again. I guess / is the only reserved character in this matter?